# Using QGIS plugin default code produces attribute error

Tags: pyqgis, attributeerror

Using Windows 10/QGIS 2.18 and QT Designer, I am creating a plugin that will create several random point selections and to place the results by appending several point layers.

So I created a "default" plugin using plugin builder.  I also inserted (literally), the .py code of the QGIS built-in plugin RandomSelection to study it.  However whenever I run run the plugin (or actually when I start QGIS), I get the following error:

> AttributeError: RandomPointMaker instance has no attribute 'parameters'

Can anyone point to where my issue is?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources

# Import the code for the dialog
from random_point_maker_dialog import RandomPointMakerDialog
import os.path
import random

from processing.core.GeoAlgorithm import GeoAlgorithm
from processing.core.GeoAlgorithmExecutionException import GeoAlgorithmExecutionException
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterSelection
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterVector
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterNumber
from processing.core.outputs import OutputVector
from processing.tools import dataobjects

from qgis.gui import QgsMapLayerComboBox
from qgis.gui import QgsMapLayerProxyModel
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry

class RandomPointMaker(GeoAlgorithm):
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
    METHOD = 'METHOD'
    NUMBER = 'NUMBER'

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgisInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'RandomPointMaker_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)


        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&Random Light Maker')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'RandomPointMaker')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'RandomPointMaker')

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('RandomPointMaker', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar."""

        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = RandomPointMakerDialog()

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            self.toolbar.addAction(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        self.allowOnlyOpenedLayers = False
        self.name, self.i18n_name = self.trAlgorithm('Random selection')
        self.group, self.i18n_group = self.trAlgorithm('Vector selection tools')

        self.methods = [self.tr('Number of selected features'),
                        self.tr('Percentage of selected features')]

        self.addParameter(ParameterVector(self.INPUT,
                                          self.tr('Input layer'), [ParameterVector.VECTOR_TYPE_ANY]))
        self.addParameter(ParameterSelection(self.METHOD,
                                             self.tr('Method'), self.methods, 0))
        self.addParameter(ParameterNumber(self.NUMBER,
                                          self.tr('Number/percentage of selected features'), 0, None, 10))
        self.addOutput(OutputVector(self.OUTPUT, self.tr('Selection'), True))


    def run(GeoAlgorithm):
              #Run method that performs all the real work

        filename = self.getParameterValue(self.INPUT)
        layer = dataobjects.getObjectFromUri(filename)
        method = self.getParameterValue(self.METHOD)

        featureCount = layer.featureCount()
        value = int(self.getParameterValue(self.NUMBER))

        layer.removeSelection()

        if method == 0:
            if value > featureCount:
                raise GeoAlgorithmExecutionException(
                    self.tr('Selected number is greater than feature count. '
                            'Choose a lower value and try again.'))
        else:
            if value > 100:
                raise GeoAlgorithmExecutionException(
                    self.tr("Percentage can't be greater than 100. Set a "
                            "different value and try again."))
            value = int(round(value / 100.0, 4) * featureCount)

        selran = random.sample(xrange(featureCount), value)

        layer.setSelectedFeatures(selran)
        self.setOutputValue(self.OUTPUT, filename)

    def unload(self):
           #Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&Random Light Maker'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
        # remove the toolbar
        del self.toolbar
```

Comment: It would be helpful, if you added whole error message including line number, file path and names etc.. The reason of getting error probably is not this file. There is no  `parameters` word used with `RandomPointMaker` instance in the code.

Comment: Good idea.... here is the entire message:  Does not look like I can format but here goes:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/QGIS/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 342, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName].initGui()
  File "C:/Users/socal/.qgis2/python/plugins\RandomPointMaker\random_light_maker.py", line 167, in initGui
    self.dlg.NUMBER(ParameterNumber(self.NUMBER,
AttributeError: RandomPointMaker instance has no attribute 'NUMBER'